# How can I delete the data after time ends?

Tags: mongoose, discord.js

I was trying to create a command that has cooldown on it. Im almost done and working perfectly fine, but the thing is. How do I create the automatic delete *if its the right term* after the time ends?

```
const cmd = client.commands.get(command) || client.commands.find(a => a.aliases && a.aliases.includes(command)) 
    if(cmd) {
        if(cmd.cooldown) {
            const cools = require("./Schema/cooldown");
            cools.findOne({
                guildID: message.guild.id,
                userID: message.author.id,
                command: cmd.name
            }, async(err, data) => {
                if(data) {
                    const cd = await cools.findOne({
                        guildID: message.guild.id,
                        userID: message.author.id,
                        command: cmd.name
                    })

                    let dateNow = ms(cd.coolDown - Date.now(), {long: true})
                    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                    .setDescription(`You already used ${cmd.name} command.`)
                    .addField("Cooldown Time:", `${dateNow}`)
                    .setColor('RANDOM')
                    .setTimestamp()

                    return message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]}) 
                } else {
                    if(cmd) cmd.execute(client, message, args, prefix)
                    new cools({
                         guildID: message.guild.id, 
                         userID: message.author.id,
                         coolDown: Date.now() + cmd.cooldown,
                         command: cmd.name
                    }).save();
                }
            })
        } 
    }
```

This is the part that I dont know where should I put it

```
const x = cd.coolDown - Date.now();
     if(x <= 0) {
           await cools.findOneAndRemove({
                   guildID: message.guild.id,
                   userID: message.author.id,
                   command: cmd.name
     })
}
```

Any hints or answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`remove()` is depricated, you can use `deleteOne()`, `deleteMany()` or `findOneAndDelete()` instead.
You can simply use the `.delete()` function also

```js
const data = await cools.findOne({ guildID: message.guild.id, userID: message.author.id, command: cmd.name });
if (data) data.delete()
```

```js
cools.findOneAndDelete({ guildID: message.guild.id, userID: message.author.id, command: cmd.name }, async (err, data) => {
       if (err) catch (err);
       if (!data) return; // Check if the data exists to prevent future crash for your bot if there was error loading or saving data
})
```

You can check the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html) about removing all documents matching the given filter

Comment: I was asking if how should I built my code file when these `let dateNow = ms(cd.coolDown - Date.now(), {long: true})` line ended, the data delete